# Vercel Automatic Branch URL not deploying

Tags: next.js, vercel

On Vercel whenever we deploy from a branch usually two preview deployment URLs are generated.

1. Automatic **unique URL**
   site-xadvghg2z-companyname.vercel.app
2. Automatic **Branch URL**
   site-git-hello-world-companyname.vercel.app

This is composed of the following pieces
[project-name]-git-[branch-name]-[scope-slug].vercel.app

[Vercel Official Documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/automatic-urls)

For all our projects on Vercel, this is how it has been working so far. However, we have one project where only the **Automatic unique URL** is deployed. The **branch url** is not deployed. Settings are similar for all projects, and they are all connected through Git Repository in Vercel.

**Example**

[Concrete example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z3PL.png)

Here **fix-branch-name** is the name of the branch. However, there is only a single domain deployed.

Next is a working example how we would expect it to behave.

[Working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNmyx.png)

Two domains are automatically deployed, the unique url and branch url.

Any idea what could be wrong ?